# How to retain filer and sort option of p-dataTable with primeng and angular?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

In simple word, I am using primeng(p-dataTable) with version-5.0.2 and angular 5, I am new to both. Here I want to save/retain, p-dataTable filter & sort option in case of navigation (like location.back()).

Comment: Please modify your question and a bit details to it. Also, add reference to `primeng` since it's not known to everyone

Comment: @BasheerKharoti thanks for reply, I will update little bit more details soon.